# How to get jQuery to 'reset' itself upon an event? IE8 and 9 padding issue?

Tags: jquery, background, refresh, internet-explorer-9, animated

I don't know a lot about jQuery, maybe this is something simple... I'm working on this website:

http://www.adaptdesign.com/misc/jtppwg/venuedirectory.html

Clicking a link in the panel on the right, such as The Atlantic Hotel, St Brelade's Bay Hotel or The Club Hotel & Spa scrolls you down the page and lights up the respective DIV, no problem. This is done with the following jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.anchorHL").anchorAnimate()
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.anchorHL").anchorAnimate().click(function() {
$('.venuedivhighlight').removeClass('venuedivhighlight');

$('a[name='+$(this).attr('href').substring(1)+']').next().addClass('venuedivhighlight');

});
});

</script>
```

the CSS for venuedivhighlight is as follows:

```
.venuedivhighlight {
background-image: url(images/anim-bg-fade.gif);
}
```

The yellow fade is done with an animated GIF. I know jQuery can achieve this animated effect but I couldn't get it working, so to save time I used this as a workaround.

With Firefox this works perfectly, but with all the other browsers the selected venue will highlight once and then with subsequent clicks and scrolls the animated background will not reload. I've noticed that when setting the CSS above to have a red background, it can be seen on all of the browsers (in FF the red appears after the animation, and in other browsers the red appears right away).

Any ideas on how I can get the GIF to refresh with every click?

On a side note I'd love a bit more padding in the yellow box, ie more space around the text when the highlighting occurs. This is fine in most browsers but when adding even a few pixels of padding, the whole thing displays as a total mess in IE8 and 9 (in earlier versions, frustratingly it looks perfect). Is there a new IE padding issue workaround that anybody knows about?

Many thanks in advance.

Chris

Adapt Design

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, I think your best bet might be to stick with your original plan and animate the color with jQuery. The problem you're most likely hitting is that jQuery can't do this out of the box. In order to animate color, you need the Effects library from jQueryUI. Check out their docs here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

So first, you'll download a custom package of jQueryUI that includes the effects lib and add it to the page, then try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.anchorHL").anchorAnimate().click(function() {
        $('.venuedivhighlight').removeClass('venuedivhighlight');
        var $el = $('a[name=' + $(this).attr('href').substring(1) + ']').next();

        // No need to set the class if the sole purpose is just to animate it later...
        $el.css({ backgroundColor: '#ff0000' });

        // Here's the magic
        setTimeout(function() {
            $el.animate({ backgroundColor: '#fff' }, 3000);
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

To answer the second part of your question, if you want to add a padding of say, 5px, around the edge of your  `.ad-basic-cell` divs, you'll need to subtract at least 10px from the width in order to do so:

```
.ad-basic-cell {
    width: 205px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jason, I downloaded jQueryUI including all 31 components as a test, referenced the JS in my HTML but the animation is not occuring. The scroll moves down to the box and it's background is red (as I can see in your code). I tried renaming $el.animate to $el.highlight as 'highlight' was one of the components for jQueryUI and 'animate' is nowhere to be found in the components list, but to no avail... any ideas?

Comment: As for the padding issue, I know exactly what you're saying, it's completely logical. IE9 seems to have thrown logic out the window unfortunately. Take a look at this, I can't figure out why it would act this way, padding is catered for by the width reduction and extending the height of the container doesn't help (it's tall enough anyway), so I'm stumped...

I've a feeling I will need to either recode from the ground up or just make do with a tight highlight area behind the text...

http://www.adaptdesign.com/misc/iepaddingissue.jpg

Comment: The reason the jQueryUI stuff isn't working is because you now have 2 versions of jQuery on your page. Check out lines 10 - 14 of your page source. You're including jQuery 1.6.x, then jQueryUI, then including jQuery 1.3.x. Remove the second jQuery declaration and give it a whirl.

Comment: Also, regarding IE9, can you hit f12 to bring up the dev tools. Let me know what the rendering settings are. I can't replicate your problem. Looks fine to me in IE9.

Comment: Ah good point, I hadn't realised that. I will give it a try on Monday morning at work and get back to you, as for the IE9 problem IENetrenderer displayed it as a mess as did the PC we have in the studio. I will let you know the settings Monday. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Jason, removing jQuery 1.3 does the trick in terms of making the animation work which is fantastic, however the 'sticky scrolling' script I have starting on line 46 doesn't work as a result. By comparing the animation script vs the sticky scrolling script I've a feeling it's just a case of the sticky script syntax needing amending to match the 1.6 style, would this be correct? If this is the case, please could you give me a few pointers? I've tried matching it to the style of the animation script but I get syntax errors...

Comment: Just getting a chance to look at your follow up comment. Are you still getting errors? I'm not seeing any popping up. If you are, I'd consider checking out the documentation for the anchorAnimate plugin and see if there are any good pointers in there.

Comment: Yep, still getting the error. It seems I can use either the animation or the sticky scrolling, and not both at the same time. I've been looking for a sticky scrolling scripts that work with jQuery 1.6 but none I've found thus far are suitable. I'm considering admitting defeat and placing static 'back to top' graphics links after every few rows... as I think the animation effect is more important.

Comment: Looks just be an incompatibility with that specific plugin. jQuery 1.5 had a few breaking changes in it, and it doesn't look like the author of that anchor scroll plugin has kept it up to date. I bet you could find another plugin that does the same thing, or fix the existing one if that bit of UI bling is important to your project.

Comment: Yeah, I'll keep on the look out. Meanwhile I figured out why IE had the padding issue. It's because of the scrolling anchors code, ie <a name="atlantichotel" id="atlantichotel"> </a>. If the DIV is wrapped INSIDE this anchor, it works but IE displays the page as a mess. If the DIV SURROUNDS the anchor, the highlight only occurs around the title of each 'advert', which isn't great. The compromise is to have no padding which displays the same way in all browsers, frustratingly... I may look into a IE-specific CSS 'hack' to see if IE9 can be treated differently as it's the stuck in the mud!

Comment: Tip of the day - sometimes the quickest way to reveal your problem is to recode the whole thing from scratch...!